# Does the value of a power sum drastically change for even or odd parity?

Tags: power-series

I was going over old HW solutions to study for an exam and I noticed something strange.

[image: Picture illustrating power sum I was trying to simplify.]

Basically, the number in the denominator was 90 based on the table I looked up the value in, but the solution to this problem said it should be 1440. The problem I'm working on specifies only even n, so I suspect that's part of it somehow.

All I could figure out was that 1440/90 = 16, or 2^4.

I suspect that's what happened there. That the denominator was multiplied by 2^4 for some reason. But why does that happen? And how is it different for odd n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** you can rewrite the sum as 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)^4}
$$
where I've used the substitution $n = 2k$ for $k = 1,2,3,\dots$

Comment: So, are you saying it's appropriate to rewrite it in that way in order to simplify, because once you simplify you no longer have an n? Because the n in this problem MUST be even. In the way you wrote it, n could be any integer. But I suppose that works because what you wrote the sum as will always be even? Maybe someone can put this into a more eloquent explanation?

Comment: *"once you simplify you no longer have an n"*: I don't understand what this means.  Anyway, see my latest edit, maybe that makes more sense.

Comment: I was just saying that pi^4/1440 (what the power sum simplifies to) doesn't have an n in it. But yes, that edit helps a lot. Thanks!